# I want to configure SES to send verification code/links to the email and one custom attribute recoveryEmail from Cognito User pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I have performed this same for forgot password by writing lambda function. But I am not getting verification code in Gmail it shows "Your verification code is {####}.

While I have tried to create an account using fake email and when I try to forgot the password, the mail receives with the verification code.

I am getting verification code in default email but not in recoveryEmail attribute.